# Write 0 characters to a file descriptor

Tags: python, windows

I have a particular hardware driver which requires me to call `_write(fd, 0, 0)` on its file descriptor in order to trigger some particular behaviour.

I'd like to be able to do this from Python - please can anyone suggest a way of achieving this?

---

EDIT (should've put this in at the beginning, sorry!):

Things that have been tried and don't work:

```
f.write("")
os.write(fd, "")
os.fdsync(fd)
```

Comment: Does `f.write("")` work?

Comment: I'm going to guess it wouldn't work, because while `""` is zero-length, it's not a null reference (address `0`).

Comment: You're probably going to have to directly call a Windows specific function to accomplish this. Take a look at the built-in `ctypes` module and the [PyWin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) module. Either way you're going to have to have some knowledge of the win32 API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need to have a null pointer (what a terrible driver design - a ioctl would have been by far better), you'll have to go via `ctypes`.

At least,

```
import ctypes
ctypes.cdll.msvcrt._write(1, 0, 0)
```

seems to work.

Comment: I don't need to have a NULL pointer, it's the writing of zero bytes that triggers what I need!

Answer (score 1):

The `os` module as a function called `write`:

```
import os
os.write(fd, b"")
```